# Why is noun+adjective allowed?

Tags: adjectives, nouns

I saw this phrase while I was reading an example of the usage of an adjective on Cambridge dictionary online i.e. included. This is the provided link: [included](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/included). The complete sentence is:

> The trip cost a total of £250, **insurance included**.

Why is it not:

> The trip cost a total of £250, **insurance is included**.

Again, another example:

> The fee covers everything, **babysitter included.**

Why again is it not:

> The fee covers everything, **babysitter is included.**

Insurance and babysitter are nouns and included is an adjective, so why is this allowed? What I'm familiar with is **adjective+noun** and I've never seen **noun+adjective** before.

Comment: The _is_ is understood. This is a standard usage when referring to prices in this way.

Comment: To expand on Kate's comment: the *meaning* of "is" is understood. To actually have "is" there, as in your examples, would require forming a complete clause with an article ("the/a/an") and either a conjunction, a semicolon, or a separate sentence.

Comment: This is similar to, if not directly related to, a construct in Latin called the [ablative absolute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_syntax#Ablative_absolute). This involved a noun and a participle put in the ablative case to express a circumstance under which the sentence occurred. It could literally be translated as "with ...", which would make sense here as well: "The trip cost a total of £250, with insurance included", "The fee covers everything, with babysitter included."

Comment: If you added "is", you would also have to add a determiner for singular count nouns. "insurance" is a non-count noun, so "insurance is included" is fine. "babysitter" is a count noun, so you'd need something like "a babysitter is included" or "this babysitter is included".

Comment: 'Babysitter' is no more a _count_ noun than insurance, in this context, and both can validly be treated in the same way. Any reference to price as a _total_ (in whatever terms) implies the presence of _multiple_ elements in arriving at that total, so it's unnecessary to explicitly provide for that: it must be so, by definition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say "insurance included" or "babysitter included" are examples of [**participial phrases**](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/gerunds_participles_and_infinitives/participles.html): they use a participle to describe something about the main sentence.  Participial phrases are very common in English.  For example,

> He sat down, *weakened by hunger*.
> *Hugging the dog*, she felt a flood of relief.

You can see how the participial phrase is not the main action of the sentence, but it tells us something about the main action.

In contrast, *insurance is included* or *babysitter is included* are complete sentences, because they have a subject (*insurance/babysitter*) and a main verb (*to be*).  You can't just ram two sentences together with a comma between them; this is an error in English called a [**comma splice**](https://advice.writing.utoronto.ca/revising/comma-splices/).  You could join them with a conjunction, like

> The trip costs $250, and insurance is included.

or

> The trip costs $250, but insurance is included.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, "included" is the past participle of "include". Past participles act much like adjectives, but there are difference. One of them, as this example shows, is that noun+participle is more allowable than noun+adjective (however, there are cases where noun+adjective is allowed).